# How to use Dto instead of Model class in hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, search, model, projection, dto

I'm trying to improve search time hibernate runs too many queries to get data which are not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Yu have a lot of possibilities:

For example you can map them with a mapper like MapStruct. You can also build your DTO manually exactely like a new object:

```
Object objectDTO = new Object();
objectDTO.setSomething(object.something);
```

Try to code something simple to begin and the community will help you :)